# Javascript OOP - non-privileged public methods with private variables

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to find a javascript OOP approach, where the variables should be private (not accessible from the outside) using non-privileged methods.

The following example should demonstrate it:

```
var Person = (function() {
var _name;
var _surname;
var _personID;
function Person(name, surname, personID) {
    _name = name;
    _surname = surname;
    _personID = personID;
}
Person.prototype.getName = function() {
    return _name;
};
Person.prototype.getSurname = function() {
    return _surname;
};
Person.prototype.getPersonID = function() {
    return _personID;
};
return Person;
})();

//Testing
var max = new Person('Max', 'Smith', 2345);
max._name = 'John';
console.log(max.getName()); // Max
console.log(max.getSurname()); // Smith
console.log(max.getPersonID()); // 2345
```

It seems to fulfill the conditions, so `max._name = 'John'` does not change the value and the methods are still getting the private values (without using .this)

But, the problem is, that creating a further object is obviously the same object, it refers to the same values:

```
//Testing
var max = new Person('Max', 'Smith', 2345);
var max2 = new Person('Max2', 'Smith2', 2345);

console.log(max.getName()); // Max2
console.log(max.getSurname()); // Smith2
console.log(max.getPersonID()); // 2345

console.log(max2.getName()); // Max2
console.log(max2.getSurname()); // Smith2
console.log(max2.getPersonID()); // 2345
```

How can I create different objects without making the values public? Is it at all possible in Javascript?

Comment: *"Is it at all possible in Javascript?"* Sure, but you will loose other benefits. I recommend to not impose concepts from other languages onto JavaScript.

Comment: encapsulation doesn't necessary have to be enforced in language level. you can do it at documentation level. e.g. `/* Variables begins with _ are private. DO NOT modify them outside this class or you will be fired */`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it at all possible in Javascript?

No, it's not. Stop searching, you'll never find an approach.
Just use privileged methods, there's nothing wrong with them.

Comment: I was already tending to the privileged methods too. Is it a good approach to use Object.freeze, to make some private methods public? Just have a look on Geoffrey Ochsner's approach.

Comment: "*use Object.freeze, to make some private methods public*" doesn't make sense to me. Geoffrey's answer basically is using a factory pattern which can be used with parasitic inheritance, but that's no different from the default constructor+prototype approach in regards to the privacy of variables or the use of privileged methods.

Comment: That said, `Object.freeze` should not do any harm - as long as you don't want to extend the objects later on, like for inheritance, and as long as it doesn't have a noticeable performance impact. Personally I've never been in a scenario where I had to use `Object.freeze` to guard against anything.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for. I also include some code for animals to demonstrate how inheritance might be done. And actually, I think you can drop the 'new' keyword (though maybe it gets re-added behind the scenes, not sure).

http://plnkr.co/edit/6nW3DtqJWEu7fZ29GMOC?p=preview

```
var Person = (function(){
  function Person(name, surname, personId){
    var _name = name, _surname = surname, _personId = personId;

    return Object.freeze({
      getName: getName,
      getSurname: getSurname,
      getPersonID: getPersonID
    });

    function getName(){
      return _name;
    }

    function getSurname(){
      return _surname;
    }

    function getPersonID(){
      return _personId;
    }
  }

  return Person;
})();

var max = new Person('Max', 'Smith', 2345);
var max2 =  Person('Max2', 'Smith2', 2346);
max._name = 'John';
console.log(max.getName()); // Max
console.log(max.getSurname()); // Smith
console.log(max.getPersonID()); // 2345

console.log(max2.getName()); // Max2
console.log(max2.getSurname()); // Smith2
console.log(max2.getPersonID()); // 2346
```

*Edit: I'm not sure my solution qualifies as 'non-privileged' based on  [Douglas Crockford's definition](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html). I do believe that page is outdated and I'm using his new syntax using [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) which means it is no longer possible to delete or alter the public methods.*

*Edit2: I shamelessly stole that syntax from [The Better Parts](https://vimeo.com/97419177#t=2316s). Give it a watch.*

Comment: I think, that you're using privileged methods here, the outer scope of Person is in this case useless, because the privileged functions are in the constructor of Person already. The `Object.freeze` approach is nice, it makes the specified methods public.
Do you think, that there is a difference between Object.freeze "methods", which are going to be visible, and privileged methods like `this.getPersonID = function(){}` ? (Thanks for your posting)

Comment: If you check out Douglas Crockford's definition of 'privileged' method he's using the 'this' syntax. He states "It is possible to delete or replace a privileged method, but it is not possible to alter it, or to force it to give up its secrets." Using his updated syntax, as I am, it is not possible to delete or alter the properties (to the best of my knowledge).